# Make spinner to dropdown automatically

Tags: android, click, android-spinner

In Android is it possible to make spinner display the list through programmatically without manually clicking the android screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize your Spinner in Activity's onCreate(). Also set its adapter and listeners if any and finally add following code at end of onCreate()

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                spinner.performClick();
            }
});
```

Comment: what if we do databinding then how we can autoclick perform in xml?